# Disable data-stylerecorder="true" Revolution Slider 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, plugins, revolution-slider

I don't get it, how can I disable all theses style added to the content ?

Can't find any option in RS6 settings ...

Any help would be appreciated !

[image]

Comment: many thanks colapsnux for your question. i have had a closer look at the logs. At the moment i failed to see what the issue is. Keep us updated!